# How can I have multiple test targets depend on each other across projects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, tvos

I have 2 frameworks Core and Extra in separate projects with separate targets for the framework and tests. I have some test data and helper functions in the Core test target that I want to use in the Extra tests, but I do not want to copy the test data files and helper methods to the Extra project. Is there a way for tests targets to depend on other other test targets similar to framework targets in a way that they can import each other's' classes and compiled resources?

Here's a diagram if that didn't make sense.

- Core.xcodeproj

  - Core.framework
  - Core.test
- Extra.xcodeproj

  - Extra.framework
  - Extra.test

Extra.framework depends on Core.framework and imports its methods without issues.
Core.test depends on Core.framework; Extra.test depends on Extra.framework. Both test targets can use the framework methods for unit testing without issues.

Let's say I have TestHelper.h|m in Core.test. If I want to use this same class in Extra.test, how do I set up Core.test as a dependency for Extra.test in a way where I can import the class and compiled resources?

Comment: It's depressing that this hasn't been answered at all.